# How to get reponse time and number of requests of pods or services in Kubernetes?

Tags: cloud, kubernetes

How can I get or calculate the response time of a pod or a service in Kubernetes?
If Kubernetes doesn't handle it, would be possible to calculate the response time of a docker container?
And how can I calculate the number of requests arriving as input in a pod or service entity?

Thanks in advance.